# After update, Glassfish 3.1.2-23 fails on startup. 3.1.1 works fine

Tags: glassfish

I updated to 3.1.2-23 today and now the thing won't start. It's a brand new install and 3.1.1 worked fine. I have uninstalled 3.1.2 and re-installed 3.1.1 from the distribution exe, and it works again. I made no other changes. I'm stumped. Anyway, here's the error after typing `asadmin start-domain domain1`. Any ideas?

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Waiting for domain1 to start ..[#|2012-03-07T18:00:52.189-0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 (build 23)|#]

[#|2012-03-07T18:00:52.588-0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly Framework 1.9.46 started in: 11ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:7676]|#]

[#|2012-03-07T18:00:52.588-0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly Framework 1.9.46 started in: 38ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]|#]

[#|2012-03-07T18:00:52.588-0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly Framework 1.9.46 started in: 20ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:3700]|#]

[#|2012-03-07T18:00:52.588-0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly Framework 1.9.46 started in: 57ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]|#]

[#|2012-03-07T18:00:52.588-0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly Framework 1.9.46 started in: 31ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:4848]|#]

.[#|2012-03-07T18:00:52.736-0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.|#]

[#|2012-03-07T18:00:52.765-0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.hibernate.validator.util.Version|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final|#]

[#|2012-03-07T18:00:52.949-0600|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|Startup service failed to start : com.sun.enterprise.security.admin.cli.SecureAdminStartupCheck|#]

[#|2012-03-07T18:00:52.976-0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin|_ThreadID=36;_ThreadName=Thread-21;|Server shutdown initiated|#]

[#|2012-03-07T18:00:52.976-0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=36;_ThreadName=Thread-21;|Already stopped, so just returning|#]


Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Grizzly-kernel-thread(1)"

Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Grizzly-kernel-thread(1)"

Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Grizzly-kernel-thread(1)"
.Error starting domain domain1.

The server exited prematurely with exit code 0.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried?

./asadmin start-domain --upgrade

When that is done you should be able to start and stop your server the usual way.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now! I waited until I absolutely had to upgrade before trying again.

Comment: No luck for me here.  It reports "Command start-domain executed successfully." then on the very next line says "The DAS was stopped." and it doesn't work...  Argh.

Comment: 1) Always take back-up copy of 3.1.1(the existing one) and after that try upgrade.
2)Just install latest one without upgrading the existing one and try to deploy the app from commandline, admin console or IDE like netbeans.
3)Investigate your business logic and ui compents executes perfectly in the new edition. For example some JSF/JPA things will not work properly in 3.1.2. You may need to copy the jars from 3.1.1 or it requires a work around.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes it even doesn't work after ./asadmin start-domain --upgrade.
If you still get the "Startup service failed to start : com.sun.enterprise.security.admin.cli.SecureAdminStartupCheck" after the command above, try following:

1. Create new domain with ./asadmin create-domain domain2
2. Backup your cacerts.jks and keystore.jks in domain1
3. Copy cacerts.jks and keystore.jks from new domain2 into domain1
4. Start domain1 ./asadmin start-domain domain1
5. Enjoy!

Then you can revert your backupped cacerts.jks and keystore.jks back. Domain will work.

Comment: Don't forget to go in and re-enable secure admin mode too if you use the Web GUI config tool!

Comment: This solution worked for me because i had an expired certificate! I deleted the certificate, and followed the above steps...